# Struggling to get the tagging screen to appear in the Docker container for the Forms Recognizer Sampler Labling Tool

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am following the instructions located at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/label-tool#set-up-the-sample-labeling-tool

I am reasonably sure that I followed the setup steps correctly. After saving a project, the tool moves directly to the tagging screen. From there, it is hung with a spinning cursor. I tried this with my corporate Azure account and my personal Azure account, each with separate subscriptions, computers, etc. Each behaves the same way. I have tried a local Docker image, and one in the cloud like the instructions show.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I was able to get it working with the help of our MSFT dev partner. It seems as though the folder feature is not working. If I put my images into the root of my blog container as jpg and not gif, and return back to the UI and navigate, the tagging feature appears.

Comment: Thanks for the update, when pointing to a folder are you pointing to a sub folder on your blob ? In reference to file types Form Recognizer supports - PDF, png, jpg and Tiff types.

Comment: I was pointing to a subfolder. I am using jpgs. I may not have had the / correct. I am not sure exactly what the issue was. Our MS development partner didn't immediately get it working either and he was the one that tipped me to the folder issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations Tom has solved the problem by himself:

> I was able to get it working, It seems as though the folder feature is not working. If I put my images into the root of my blog container as jpg and not gif, and return back to the UI and navigate, the tagging feature appears.

I help him post it as an answer, this can be beneficial to other community members.